# How can I look up a value in a dict if I'm creating a variable with the Dicts name?

Tags: python

Easier explained with code:

```
#test data
Day1={  
      'data1':0,
      'data2':   1,
      'data3':    2,
      'data4':    3,
      'data5':    4,
      'data6':    5,
      'data7':    4,
      'data8':    3,
      'data9':    2,
      'data10':    1}

Day2= {  
       'data1':    2,
       'data2':    3,
       'data3':    4,
       'data4':    5,
       'data5':    6,
       'data6':    6,
       'data7':    7,
       'data8':    6,
       'data9':    4,
       'data10':    3}

Day3= {    
       'data1':    2,
       'data2':    4,
       'data3':    5,
       'data4':    6,
       'data5':    7,
       'data6':    6,
       'data7':    8,
       'data8':    6,
       'data9':    5,
       'data10':    4}

Day4= {   
       'data1':    2,
       'data2':    4,
       'data3':    5,
       'data4':    6,
       'data5':    7,
       'data6':    6,
       'data7':    6,
       'data8':    8,
       'data9':    5,
       'data10':    4}

AllData= {'Day1':Day1,'Day2':Day2,'Day3':Day3,'Day4':Day4}


#Number of items in AllData dictionary
AllDataSize = len(AllData)
CurrentDayCounter=0

while CurrentDayCounter < AllDataSize:
    CurrentDayCounter=CurrentDayCounter+1
    CurrentDay = 'Day%s' % (CurrentDayCounter)
    #print AllData[CurrentDay]
    #add the nodes
    for day in AllData[CurrentDay]:
        print CurrentDay
        day = "%s" % (day)
        print CurrentDay[day] #does not work gives an error: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
        print CurrentDay[1] #works by providing a result 'a', which is the second letter in Day
        #print 'For ', CurrentDay, ' subgroup ', day,' contains ', CurrentDay[day], ' has been added to graph.'
        dayName =  "%s-%s" % (CurrentDay, Day1[day])
        #Do not create edges if its the first day
        if CurrentDay != "Day1":
            yesterday = CurrentDayCounter - 1
            print 'today is ', CurrentDayCounter, ' and yesterday is ', yesterday
```

When I do print `CurrentDay[day]` I get an error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str` but CurrentDay[1] gives a result of a(which is the middle letter of the variable.  I want to use the variable to search the dictionary as opposed to pull up a letter position.

I suspect the way, I'm doing this is totally wrong, so is there a correct way to do this?

Thanks!
p.s. sorry for the bad code, I'm just playing around with networkx, I think I removed all references to it but if I missed anything just ignore it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line (65) should be:

```
print AllData[CurrentDay][day]
```

The error message occurs because `print CurrentDay[day]` prints the `day`th character in the string `CurrentDay`

Comment: Thank you, I kind of am a bit confused though.  If day='data1', then why is it not the same as Day2['data1'] which works on the command line(but not as the variable?)

Comment: I really, really think you need to go back to some reference material and think more about what you're doing. The more I look at the code, the less sure I am about what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: `"foobar"[0]` is `"f"` because strings can be indexed like lists and dictionaries. So when you say `CurrentDay[day]` the variable `CurrentDay` is a `str` type so you just get a letter back.

Answer (score 1):

```
for day in AllData[CurrentDay]:
```

`AllData[CurrentDay]` is a `dict`. Iterating over this with `day` causes `day` to take on all the **key** values. Thus, `'data1'`, `'data2'` etc. These are not suitable indices into the string.

Once you have that fixed, take out the

```
day = '%s' % (day)
```

bit, too. That is silly; you're **forcing** the value to be a string when that's exactly what you **don't** want.

Comment: I don't understand why its not okay to use them as indices?  on the command line Day3['data1'] works, so what's the difference if I'm typing it manually vesus pulling the value from a variable?

Comment: It has nothing to do with where your data comes from and everything to do with **what kind of data it is**. `Day3` is a `dict` whose keys happen to be strings. A string is a sequence type. `x[y]` means "the 'y'th element of x". What is the `apple`'th letter of `banana`?

Answer (score 1):

Why use dicts at all? The keys you are using are redundant replacements for list indices.

For example:

```
AllData = [ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4, 3],  ...  ]
```

and you can call each value by:

```
AllData[Some_Day][Some_Data]
```

of course if you're just messing around with dictionary objects, then the previous poster had the correct solution.

Comment: I'm just playing around, I think when I really use it the format might be different.  Good point though, I never thought about it.